# Passport Js - where is the email parameter defined?

Tags: passport.js

In my passport-config.js:

```
function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email) 
    if(user == null) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'no user with that email'});
    }

    try {
        if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Password Incorrect'});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
    }
}
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email'}, authenticateUser));
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id));
});
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

In my server.js:

```
const users = [];

const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
initializePassport(
    passport,
    email => { return users.find(user => user.email == email)},
    id => { return users.find(user => user.id == id)}
);
```

In my login.ejs:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<!-- any errors gets displayed here -->
<%= messages.error %>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
Don't have an account? <a href="/register">register</a>!
```

I'm learning from this code and I'm not sure where the `email` parameter in the `authenticateUser()` function is defined - how does the computer know it's referring to `name="email"` in login.ejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

```
name="email"
```

refers to

```
req.body.email
```

You probably have a post method like

```
app.post('/register', blablabla)
.
.
  email: req.body.email
```